# Why click converts all arguments into lowercase

Tags: python-click

I would like to make an UPPER_CASE_PARAMETER into an argument to the function which is named in the same way.
As I understand the convention is that all arguments to the function are variables and thus are lowercase, however I can't locate any mention of that in the documentation. Is it documented in any way?

So I want MY_ARG to get a value from cli.

```py
def cli(MY_ARG: str):
    ...
```

P.S.
I can not find these changes in the documentation of click https://github.com/pallets/click/pull/1055.

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the solution you have written which produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: @itprorh66, I have added an example.

Comment: While in Python the convention is to use lowercase names for variables, this is not a hard and fast rule.  It is valid to define your argument as MY_ARG and python in and of itself will not throw any error.  Depending on the IDE you use and its settings, you may get a complaint from the IDE since the Uppercase name isn't pep compliant but I can't say for sure.